# not being able to scroll down in tableview ios app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

im developing an ios app, which is similiar to instagram, however it is not scrolling down the page and showing all the images, why is that?
this is the feed controller, it is also showing an error which says fatal: index out of range, I feel like this may be connected. I cannot seem to scroll down and view the other pictures which i have uploaded.

```
  import UIKit
  import Firebase
  import SDWebImage


class FeedController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableV: UITableView!
var userEmailArray = [String] ()
var userCommentArray = [String] ()
var likeArray = [Int] ()
var userImageArray = [String] ()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableV.delegate = self
  //  tablev.datasource = self
    tableV.dataSource = self
 getDataFromFirestore()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userEmailArray.count

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellTable" , for: indexPath) as! Feed
       cell.user.text = userEmailArray[indexPath.row]
       cell.like.text = String(likeArray [indexPath.row])

       cell.comment.text = userCommentArray[indexPath.row]
       cell.imageee.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.userImageArray[indexPath.row]))
       return cell
   }
func getDataFromFirestore(){

    let fireStoreDatabase = Firestore.firestore()
  //  let settings = fireStoreDatabase.settings
    //settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
  //  fireStoreDatabase.settings = settings
    fireStoreDatabase.collection("post").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }else{
            if  snapshot?.isEmpty != true && snapshot != nil {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                   let documentID =  document.documentID


                    if let postedBy = document.get("postedby") as? String {
                        self.userEmailArray.append(postedBy)
                    }
                    if let postComment = document.get("postComment") as? String{
                        self.userCommentArray.append(postComment)
                    }
                    if let likes = document.get("likes") as? Int{
                        self.likeArray.append(likes)
                    }
                    if let imageUrl = document.get("imageurl") as? String {
                        self.userImageArray.append(imageUrl)
                    }
                    self.tableV.reloadData()
                }
               // snapshot!.documents



            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Check if scrolling is enabled, and what is the `userEmailArray` count?

Comment: Try printing userEmailArray.count, that might be zero.

Comment: i keep getting index out of range error

Comment: Using multiple arrays in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` is a bad idea. Create a struct to hold your data and use a single array of those structs.